# How do I monitor (non-zero-downtime) Unicorn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

I'm finding an awful lot of conflicting information about monitoring Unicorn, with people saying other config scripts are wrong, and posting their own. There seems to be no main config that Just Works™

I'm assuming `preload_app` and zero-downtime deployment are the main culprit. I'd love to have that, but for now I'm more interested in just getting monitoring running, period. So currently I have all those settings turned off.

Right now I'm using [capistrano-unicorn](https://github.com/sosedoff/capistrano-unicorn) which is a really great gem.

It gives me all the capistrano deploy hooks I need to reload unicorn. The app has successfully deployed already with it.

The main thing I want to do now is...

a) Make sure unicorn starts up automatically on server failure/reboot

b) Monitor unicorn to restart workers that die/hang/whatever.

If I'm using this gem, what might be the best approach to complete my goals (keeping in mind I don't necessarily need zero downtime)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Engine yard uses [Monit](http://mmonit.com/monit/), and it's a pretty little utility that does exactly what you need!

Here is the configuration for unicorn:

```
check process unicorn
  with pidfile /path/to/unicorn.pid
  start program = "command to start unicorn"
    as uid yourUID and gid yourGID
    stop program = "command to stop unicorn"
    as uid yourUID and gid yourGID
  if mem > 255.0 MB for 2 cycles then restart
  if cpu > 100% for 2 cycles then restart

  check process unicorn_worker0
  with pidfile /path/to/unicorn_worker_0.pid
  if mem > 255.0 MB for 2 cycles then exec "/bin/bash -c '/bin/kill -6 `cat /path/to/unicorn_worker_0.pid` && sleep 1'"
...
```